# Flutter tutorial examples will not compile

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, yaml, pubspec

I wish to learn DART in the Flutter environment by using pub.dev tutorial examples. However, none will compile as I currently understand how to use Android Studio.
For example, 'snake.dart' from the 'sensors-plus' pubspec package fails with several errors, all evidently related to the error messages below:

```
Invalid depfile: C:\dev\startup_namer\.dart_tool\flutter_build\fa7e54a26ab5260b254ace7327865552\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\dev\startup_namer\.dart_tool\flutter_build\fa7e54a26ab5260b254ace7327865552\kernel_snapshot.d
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'pubspec' in 'package:pubspec/sensors_plus/sensors_plus.dart'.
    lib/main.dart:9:8: 
Error: Not found: 'package:pubspec/sensors_plus/sensors_plus.dart'
    import 'package:pubspec/sensors_plus/sensors_plus.dart';
```

Following the hint to 'import package:pubspec/sensors_plus/sensors_plus.dart' does not resolve the errors.
I read that something must be done in the pubspec.yaml file, but where is this file? It is not listed in the project hierarchy.
Thoughts?

[The results of flutter doctor -v on my Windows10 platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jogAy.png)

Comment: Which installation instructions did you follow?  And on what platform (windows?)?

Comment: hi. welcome to stackoverflow . please edit your post and add result of this statement from android studio terminal  : (flutter doctor -v) . then add picture from pubspec.yaml file Where dependencies are included.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz thanks for your comment. Mine is a Windows10 system, and I've edited the original post with a screen shot of 'flutter doctor -v' for your consideration. Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @EsmaeilAhmadipour thanks for your comment. Mine is a Windows10 system, and I've attached a screen shot of 'flutter doctor -v' for your consideration. I would very much like to include a similar shot of the pubspec.yaml file, but I don't know where to find it. The default 'button press counter' program that comes with Android Studio runs perfectly, but I have no idea where the 'pubspec.yaml' file resides. As stated in my original post, I don't know where to find it as it does not appear in the project hierarchy. Many thanks!